# Whenever I try to import a python library I always get "ModuleNotFoundError" what do I do?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, import

Whenever I try to import the libraries "beautifulsoup" or "requests" I always get the same error. The error I get looks like this... ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'. I already have these libraries installed I just can't seem to figure out what's wrong.

If you look at the image below, I noticed when I use the recommended interpreter I get a problem saying "Import "bs4" could not be resolved from source". However, when I select one of the other Python 3.10.7 interpreters the problem goes away(see second picture). Either way I still get the Module not found error. I was thinking this info might help diagnose the problem I'm having.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Each installation of python has a different place where packages are installed. Check the tool you are using to see what its preferred method of package installation is. If all else fails, in your IDE's shell, `import sys; print(sys.executable)`. Then you could use that executable on the command line to do `/path/to/my/python3 -m pip install whatever-i-want-to-install`. Or maybe you are using conda which has a different method.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to cross check **environmental variable** path of python and editor **interpreter path**
so, may be possible you downloaded that library but it available on another path for that he can't reach out and you get error

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).